# How to stretch an image in vegas? Tips? (Reference image in body)

Tags: video-editor, editing, vegas-pro

[image: What I got]

That's as far as I had gone, I am trying to fit the image in the box but I just can't figure it out. no matter how much I stretch it or rotate it,  it just doesn't work

Here's another image so you guys know my pan/crop settings
[image: Pan/crop settings]

and if you need to try it yourself, here's a green screen. if you at least get a still frame I guess I can animate it from there (Though, actually tell me how did you get it to work)
[image: Green screen of what I am trying to do]
[image: Image that I am trying to fit in]

I also wonder, if I already have the mask, and it's already animated and stuff, could that help me?

Edit:Wait, do you guys need a green screen lol? I am going to leave it there just in case but I don't think you guys need it (Note:The green screen was made by me, by using the mask. I got the mask with the keyframes, I really hope that's useful)

Answer (score 0):

I believe most of this effect can be achieved using **Deform FX**.

For true perspective, you need **3D track motion**.

I have not used either but here are some links:

[Perspective](https://forums.creativecow.net/docs/forums/post.php?forumid=24&postid=959092&univpostid=959092&pview=t)

[How do I skew a video clip?](https://www.vegascreativesoftware.info/us/forum/how-do-i-skew-a-video-clip--69260/)

Comment: It's been so long that I even forgot about this, I still have the project file so I'll try, thanks man

Comment: I can't make it work with deform fx, but maybe I am just not trying hard enough, this effect is hard to understand

I tried 3d track motion and well, I feel blessed but at the same time it didn't do enough of a good job. I tried and I just can't make it work, if there's something else to know or if in the future I learn something I'll go back to editing this